# Video is not playing fetched from azure blob storage

Tags: android, android-studio, android-videoview, azure-blob-storage

I am creating an application in which I upload any video from mobile through browser
It stores in blob storage but when I try to fetch it and play it in media player of android there is error in logcat saying "can't open the file" and same is happening if I upload a video from laptop which record by mobile
Why this is happening ? Does codec format of mobile video plays vital role in it ? If yes then what should I do
Thank you in advance

Comment: Which codec format you use? I succeeded in playing the `.mp4` and `.avi` video fetched from blob storage.

Comment: @DorisLv my codec format is same, is bit rate can be a issue because when i lower the bit rate and upload the same video i can access **.mp4**  file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are something we need to check when streaming video in Azure storage:

**1. Check your upload tools.**

> Includes the **tools** and the **settings**, such as **bit rate**. Sometimes the issue comes with half-baked tools or the transmitting settings.

**2. Check your Blob Type.**

> Make sure your videos are BlockBlobs. Check the header x-ms-blob-type. There are BlockBlobs and PageBlobs … but for streaming video you want BlockBlobs.

**3. Check your [storage version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-account-overview?toc=/azure/storage/blobs/toc.json#types-of-storage-accounts). It is no problem if we use General-purpose v2 accounts by default.**

> Azure Storage offers several types of storage accounts. Each type supports different features and has its own pricing model. Consider these differences before you create a storage account to determine the type of account that is best for your applications.

**4. Check your video codec format and size.**

> Storage clients default to a 128 MiB maximum single blob upload. You can see the details in [block blobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/understanding-block-blobs--append-blobs--and-page-blobs#about-block-blobs). For Input video codecs supported, you can refer to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/previous/media-services-media-encoder-standard-formats#input-video-codecs).

**Reference:**  [this blog](https://blog.thoughtstuff.co.uk/2014/01/streaming-mp4-video-files-in-azure-storage-containers-blob-storage/) post by Tom.